# Does Scala have an operator similar to Haskell's `$`?

Tags: function, scala, operators

Does Scala have an operator similar to [Haskell's `$`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-)?

```
-- | Application operator.  This operator is redundant, since ordinary
-- application @(f x)@ means the same as @(f '$' x)@. However, '$' has
-- low, right-associative binding precedence, so it sometimes allows
-- parentheses to be omitted; for example:
--
-- >     f $ g $ h x  =  f (g (h x))
--
-- It is also useful in higher-order situations, such as @'map' ('$' 0) xs@,
-- or @'Data.List.zipWith' ('$') fs xs@.
{-# INLINE ($) #-}
($)                     :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x                   =  f x
```

Comment: For the sake of making the question stand alone, it would be nice if you explained what that Haskell construct is / does.

Comment: $ is  apparently right-associative and has a low precedence http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#function-application.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's written "apply"

```
fn apply arg
```

There's no standard punctuation operator for this, but it would be easy enough to add one via library pimping.

```
  class RichFunction[-A,+B](fn: Function1[A, B]){ def $(a:A):B = fn(a)}
  implicit def function2RichFunction[-A,+B](t: Function1[A, B]) = new RichFunction[A, B](t)
```

In general, while Scala code is much denser than Java, it's not quite as dense as Haskell.  Thus, there's less payoff to creating operators like '$' and '.'

Comment: One of the bigger wins of `$` is its use in operator sections: `(f $)` and `($ x)`, which don't exist in Scala (you'd write `f(_)` and `_(x)` instead, but you can't do that in Haskell).